# How can I test GraphQL of magento 2.3.0 in Wamp Server?

Tags: localhost, wamp, magento2.3.0, graphql

I have installed magento2.3.0 in localhost wamp server, It is working fine.
When I'm trying to test GraphQL for PWA studio, I'm getting this error "TypeError: Failed to fetch".
[image: GraphQL Screenshot]

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: facing same issue.. anyone have a solution ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153599)

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track but you can easily view Documentation when you click on Docs on the right top corner.

See screenshot with an example for the Category Query and the Documentation in the right sidebar.

[image: GraphQl Docs Example]

Comment: current it's showing **NO SCHEMA AVAILABLE** in Docs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your storefront is working
2. Switch to `developer` mode
3. Set the GraphiQL client endpoint to *hostname*/graphql

Does the Documentation Explorer (Docs tab) load? Do you still receive the error?

Comment: the storefront is working on `developer` mode on wamp server but still, the same issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

to put the domain like **http://mage230.localhost/graphql** and not **http://mage230/graphql**

I had the same issue, but in my case I forgot the **http://** now with a url **http://mydomain.test/graphql** it works.

Hope it helps.